# opamp output voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was trying to solve the below question. 
As per my understanding at t=0+ the difference voltage between (Vnoninvering -Vinverting)=-2.5v so output will change to -5. After then as Vin increases it will behave like normal noninverting amplifier with gain 2. The output will be distorted to give 5v.

Edit: The question is to draw output waveform Vo over time where time varies from time=0 to time= infinity.
[image]

Comment: I am still not clear what you want to know? My guess is the transient nature of opamp (at t=0+)!!

Comment: *As per my understanding at t=0+ the difference voltage between (Vnoninvering -Vinverting)=-2.5v* Explain **why** you make that (wrong) assumption. An opamp in with negative feedback will always try to make the input voltage difference **zero**. Only when it cannot do that you should assume otherwise.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: He's not assuming it; it's stated in the image. It must be a start-up transient.

Comment: @Transistor OK, you conclude that from intitial Vo = +5V so - input = 2.5 V but +in put is 0 V. That makes it an inconsistent question as no information is given about the transient behavior. Also, the situation Vo = 5V while Vin = 0 V is not a **proper solution** for this circuit. I think Vo = 5V initially is a typo and should say: Vo = 0 V initially.

Answer (score 1):

- The opamp is wired in an inverting configuration.
- The output will attempt to drive the inverting input to match the non-inverting input so that the voltage difference between them is zero.
- At t = 0 \$ V_+ = 0 \$ so \$ V_- = 0 \$. This means that \$ V_{OUT} = 0 \$ too.
- If the question is how does the opamp recover from saturation at power-up then we don't have enough information. As an approximation we can say that it immediately drops to zero.

Comment: perhaps a better approximation would be that it 'quickly' drops to zero, as fast as it can but limited by unspecified time constants.